# Boolean observable not getting passed between components

Tags: angular

Im using angular4 for a dashboard and Im tying to hide one div when a user clicks on div in a separate component. Ive created a service with a boolean observable but when I click on the button to hide the div the service is updated with the new value but the other div isn't detecting the change

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";


@Injectable()
export class ToggleParamsService {


  toggleReportAgeSentiment: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;


  constructor() {

    this.toggleReportAgeSentiment = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

    this.toggleReportAgeSentiment.asObservable();


  }

  toggleReportAgeSentiment(showHide: boolean)
  {
    this.toggleReportAgeSentiment.next(showHide) ;
  }



}
```

This is the component then that Im expecting to hide when the parameter is updated. I can see the updates being made if I log to console in the service but Its not making into this component

**Component**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ToggleParamsService} from '../../../../shared/services/toggle-params-service/toggle-params.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-report-age-by-sentiment',
  providers: [ToggleParamsService],
  templateUrl: './report-age-by-sentiment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report-age-by-sentiment.component.less']
})
export class ReportAgeBySentimentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() episodeReport: any;
  showHide;

  constructor(private toggle: ToggleParamsService) { }   //

  ngOnInit() {
    this.toggle.toggleReportAgeSentiment.subscribe(showHide => this.showHide = showHide);


  }



  changeShowAgeSentiment(){
    this.toggle.toggleReportAgeSentiment(!this.showHide);
  }

}
```

**Template**

```
<div *ngIf="showHide == true">
    <div class = "col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-8 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-8 col-md-4 col-md-offset-8 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-8 arrow-down" >

      <!--<svg height="30" width="60" class="arrow-down-open">-->
      <!--<polygon points="0,0 30,30 0,60" style="fill:#38405e;"></polygon>-->
      <!--</svg>-->

      <img src = "assets/img/arrow-down.png" class = "arrow-down-open" alt = "arrow-down" width = "60px"
           height = "30px" />
    </div>
  <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" (click) = "changeShowAgeSentiment()">
      <div class = "widget clearfix" >
        <div class = "widget-header">Sentiment By Age Range</div>
        <div class = "widget-body-no-top-padding">
          <div style = "min-height: 278px; width: 100%;">
            <app-report-age-by-sentiment-chart-display
              [episodeReport]="episodeReport"></app-report-age-by-sentiment-chart-display>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "widget-base"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Is there something fundamental Im missing here or how do I make the component detect a change?

Comment: Everything seems to be alright. Try removing this line: `this.toggleReportAgeSentiment.asObservable();`

Comment: Tried removing that line but its still not picking up any change

Comment: show us `report-age-by-sentiment.component.html`

Comment: added the component html

Comment: I just noticed you have the same name of `toggleReportAgeSentiment` for function and BehaviorObject<boolean>

Comment: opps ya Ive updated the function name now to be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I had left this for a while but Ive come back to it now and I figured out what exactly was going wrong.

The issue was the each of my components was creating a separate instance of the service that they were subscribed to. When one was updating the other wasnt seeing the updates because it wasnt subscribed to the same instance.

To resolve this I moved providers from each service up to the root component and that then shares the service amount each of the branches

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you aren't actually waiting until the response fires and returns the value. you are just calling the response. Try adding a `.subscribe()` to your service call.

```
changeShowAgeSentiment(){
    this.toggle.toggleReportAgeSentiment(!this.showHide).subscribe(res => this.showHide = res;
  }
```